# Automatically login in Django 1.8

Tags: python, django

This question has been asked a lot on SO, but none of those solutions have worked for me. I'm wondering what I'm missing. I'm using the example from [Effective Django](http://www.effectivedjango.com/). It had me create a "register" form, which redirects to '/' after success. The root page redirects to a login form if the user isn't logged in already. All I want is for the registration form to automatically log the user in upon registration.

I've created a `RegisterView()` in `views.py`, which just attempts to authenticate/login users in `form_valid()`:

```
class RegisterView(CreateView):
  template_name = 'register.html'
  form_class = forms.UserCreateForm
  success_url='/'

  def form_valid(self, form):
    user = form.save()
    user = authenticate(username=self.request.POST['username'], password=self.request.POST['password1'])
    login(self.request, user)
    return super(RegisterView, self).form_valid(form)
```

This sort of works. I tried raising an exception if `user.is_authenticated() == False`, and no exception is raised. However, by the time the browser redirects to `success_url`, apparently the login information is lost and the `@login_required` decorator makes the user login before viewing `/`.

I also tried doing `user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'` before the call to `login(...)`; and I also set `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` to the same.

Has something changed significantly in 1.8 to prevent this? Everything I've seen online has this as the solution, but it simply doesn't work for me.

Note, after registering, the user *can* login manually.

Comment: I noticed you are using a CreateView, have you tried using FormView instead?

Comment: @Joseph CreateView is a subclass of FormView.

Comment: @Joseph actually I tried using FormView and now it works exactly as I expect it to. Why does that work, if (as Rod mentioned) CreateView is a subclass of FormView?

Comment: user = authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['username'], password=form.cleaned_data['password1'])
Befor this print out cleaned_data for username and password. If you get what u have entered the cleaned_data should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem when I was doing my own website in Django 1.8. It turns out that CreateView inherits from FormMixin, not FormView. Try inheriting from FormView, and that should get the desired results without compromising any other functionality.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview

Comment: I'm not sure why (yet), but this solution worked. I'm curious what exactly is responsible for this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I mostly prefer class based views to functions based at times, though both will be required somehow. 
To answer your question, I'm also learning it, I had the same problem, and that's how it's to be from the Django documentation:
- In your settings.py, you should have something like this:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (

    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
LOGIN_URL = 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'view where to redirect user'
SITE_ID = 1
```

and in my registration template, my submit button will look something like:

```
<input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Login">
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% if next %}{{ next }}{% else %}{% url 'template or view where to redirect to' %}{% endif %}">.
```

So the second  tag redirect the user to whatever page you want him to go to after, registration or login. I used for the case you needed to comment on an article which requires you to login first, so once logged in, it's going to be logical to redirect the user to the previous page. So that's how I achieved it.
Hope it's gonna help

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood OP's question- they are looking to have the user automatically be logged in (i.e, session cookie established) after registration. Currently, the user is redirected to the login page after registration. That's a bad user experience because they enter their registration info (email and password) and then immediately have to enter it again to login.

Comment: Ok got your explanation, but what I achieved was the same if I'm not wrong, I provided a @login_required in order for a person to comment to an article. You must login to comment, if not you'll have to register, and by clicking on submit in the registration templates, it redirects you to the article you're about to comment with you logged in now.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you shared above, you are supposed to check if `user = authenticate(username=self.request.POST['username'], assword=self.request.POST['password1'])
returns a value before invoking`login_user(user)`

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    user = form.save()
    user = authenticate(username=self.request.POST['username'], password=self.request.POST['password1'])
    if user is not None:            
        login(self.request, user)
        # this is the only time the user would be logged in.
    return super(RegisterView, self).form_valid(form)
```

check (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login) for more info.
`